# Trouble with form.submit() and form.reset()

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I am trying to submit a POST request to my flask API using form.submit() and then reset the form using form.reset(). In my javascript code, I am able to do form.submit() and the data is posted to my database successfully, however, if I follow that with form.reset(), the data is NOT added to my database but the form resets. Any idea why I get this?

**Flask:**

```
class Signup(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'signup'
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(200))
    flag_1 = db.Column(db.String(1))
    flag_2 = db.Column(db.String(1))


    def __init__(self, email, flag_1, flag_2):
        self.email =  email
        self.flag_1 = flag_1
        self.flag_2 = flag_2

@app.route('/signup', methods=['POST'])
def signup():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form['email']
        flag_1 = request.form['flag_1']
        flag_2 = request.form['flag_2']

        if email == '':
            return       
        if db.session.query(Signup).filter(Signup.email == email).count() == 0:
            data = Signup(email, flag_1, flag_2)
            db.session.add(data)
            db.session.commit()
            return        
        return
```

**HTML:**

```
<form
        id="signup-form"
        name="signup-form"
        action="http://127.0.0.1:5000/signup"
        method="post"
      >
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" /><br />

        <label for="flag_1"> Flag 1:</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="flag_1" value="Y" /><br />
        <input type="hidden" name="flag_1" value="N" />

        <label for="flag_2"> Flag 2:</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="flag_2" value="Y" /><br />
        <input type="hidden" name="flag_2" value="N" />

        <button type="submit" id="signup-btn">Sign me up!</button>
      </form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
document.querySelector("#signup-btn").addEventListener("click", function () {
  const signupForm = document.getElementById("signup-form");
  signupForm.submit();
  signupForm.reset(); // if i have just one of either submit or reset, they work, but if I have both, the form just resets
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Default submit process will reload the page from the action url. The reset seems pointless unless you want to submit using ajax and not reload the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`submit()` does not submit the form instantly. It sets up a submit to happen when the event loop is free.

The browser keeps running your JS and resets the form.

Then the form submits, but with the default values because you reset it.

Typically, resetting the form at that stage would be pointless even if that wasn't the case. The browser will navigate to the page returned from the form submission, even if contains identical HTML, the rendered form will contain the values specified as default in that HTML.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. What would be a workaround in this case?

Comment: A workaround for what? As I said in the last paragraph, the reset seems pointless.

Comment: I want to fill in the form, click submit and send the data to my database, and then have the form reset to default so I can fill in another entry and repeat... sorry if my understanding is a little off

Comment: Since the browser will load a new page when it submits a form, just don't try to reset it. (If you want it to have a blank form on the new page it loads then make sure a new form is returned on that page).

Comment: Makes sense, i'm working on a chrome extension though so not sure how to return that new page, i'll do some digging. Thank you!